# Problems with web service GetList. List not found!

Tags: web-services

I'm have some trouble using the GetList web service. It does work sometimes but not at the start of the day!?!

Here is my code:

```
    public static void ListSurveys(string serverName)
    {
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serverName + SERVICE_SITEDATA_URL);
        SiteDataSoapClient client = new SiteDataSoapClient("SiteDataSoap", endpoint);

        _sList[] lists;
        uint count = client.GetListCollection(out lists);
        foreach (_sList list in lists)
        {
            if (list.BaseType == "Survey")
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(list.Title + ", " + list.InternalName);

                _sListMetadata meta;
                _sProperty[] props;
                uint glc = client.GetList(list.InternalName, out meta, out props);
                System.Console.WriteLine(meta.Title);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I fetch all the lists using **GetListCollection** and then, if it is a survey, I try to get the List information using GetList. I use the List GUID as the list name. An exception is thrown. The SOAP body is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Eine Ausnahme vom Typ Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException wurde ausgelÃ¶st.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
          Die Liste ist nicht vorhanden.

          Die ausgewÃ¤hlte Seite enthÃ¤lt eine Liste, die nicht vorhanden ist. Die Liste kÃ¶nnte von einem anderen Benutzer gelÃ¶scht worden sein.
        </errorstring>
        <errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x82000006</errorcode>
      </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The error message says that the list was not found and might have been deleted by someone else. This is strange because my code had fetched the GUID of the list just milliseconds earlier!

Can anyone explain what is going on here? I had the same problem yesterday and at some point it just went away. Unfortunately it came back this morning.

**UPDATE**
As I was writing the question I had an idea. I visited the survey overview page and tried the webservice again. It worked!! Going to the list of surveys page was not enough - I had to go to the overview page itself. Seems the lists need to be 'woken up' each morning. Is this a bug?

Comment: @paul: There is a small chance this related question may help, although it's about workflow: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/741/first-execution-of-workflow-in-the-day-always-fails

Comment: Have I answered your question adequately? Please let me know If I can provide any further detail.

Comment: @Wartickler - sorry no idea. I have managed to get out of all Sharepoint work :-)

Comment: @paul lol - I hear you. However, Since there have been a couple of upvotes (and because it really is the right answer) could you please check it as the answer? I'm doing a little cleanup on some answers that have been left hanging for a while...

Comment: @wartickler - +1. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the application pool isn't alive yet. We have our load-balanced servers send each other a 'stay-alive' http request through a script that keeps them all immediately responsive. Examples of that are all over the place.

SP goes to sleep after 15 or 20 minutes of inactivity.

Good luck!

Comment: Did this answer the question?